# Why is my webdrive being skipped when specific variable is used

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, undetected-chromedriver

When I use webdrive to click on element and if I put specific variable in it, it just skips over the webdriver and continues to run the rest of code. Variable in question is market3 and if instead of {market3} I put any other text it works normally.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//h3[@class='runner-name' and text()='{market3}']//ancestor::tr//label[@class and text()='{odds}']"))).click()
```

This is how I get value for {market3}

```
matchname = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/nav/valuebet/event/')]")))).text

matchname1 = matchname

elif "1" in market2:
    market3 = matchname1.split(sep, 1)[0]
    market3 = market3.strip()
    print(market3)
```

Comment: Is this part intended `label[@class `? Shouldn't that class have a value?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus If I put any other variable or text where {market3} is, it works. I can put {odds} instead of {market3} and webdriver works, but when I put {market3}, driver just doesn't run at all, but it runs when I put anything else. I can put {odds} in both places and it runs, but with {market3}, it doesn't

Comment: what does this `print(market3)` print?

Comment: @KunduK club names : FC Barcelona, Real Madrid, Valencia, Sevilla, Dos Santos, names like that